# Recursive function in Prolog

Tags: function, recursion, prolog, clpfd

I try to calculate recursive function:

```
f(x, y) = 0 if x = 0;
f(x, y) = 1 if x = 1;
f(x, y) = y*y*f(x-2,y) if x>1.
```

I tried this way:

```
f(0,_,0).
f(1,_,1).
f(X,Y,Z):-
          X>1,
          XX is X-2,
          ZZ = Y*Y*Z,
          f(XX,Y,ZZ).
```

I can only obtain true/false. How can I calculate value of this function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `is/2` for arithmetic assignment (`=/2` is used for equivalence under substitution). E.g., `XX is X-2`.

Comment: The first two rules can be replaced with `f(0,_,0).` and `f(1,_,1).`

Comment: Ted Hopp, Wouter Beek, I changed, but it doesn't help. I can't receive result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last rule looks a little odd to me. I'd try something like this:

```
f(X,Y,Z) :-
    X > 1,
    XX is X-2,
    f(XX,Y,ZZ),
    Z is Y * Y * ZZ.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily turn this into a true relation if you simply use CLP(FD) constraints:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

f(0, _, 0).
f(1, _, 1).
f(X, Y, Z):-
        X #> 1,
        XX #= X-2,
        Z #= Y*Y*ZZ,
        f(XX, Y, ZZ).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- f(X, 5, Z).
X = Z, Z = 0 ;
X = Z, Z = 1 ;
X = 2, Z = 0 ;
X = 3, Z = 25 .
```